# Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException

Tags: xamarin.android

I have an aplication written in Mono Android that has a form and displays data in a list. The application works fine.
But now I am trying to add another field to the layout:

```
   <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textDeliveryNo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="12345"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/title"
            android:textSize="20px"

   />
```

I modified the activity acordingly to set this field with its value:

```
 //Get our object for this position         
     var item = items[position];                        
     var view = (convertView ??                 
                context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(                 
                    Resource.Layout.DeliveriesListItem,                                parent,                  
                    false)) as LinearLayout;            

     //Find references to each subview in the list item's view          
     var imageItem = view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.imageItem) as ImageView;
     var textDeliveryNo = view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.textDeliveryNo) as TextView;
     var textDeliveryName = view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.textDeliveryName) as TextView;
     var textDeliveryAddress = view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.textDeliveryAddress) as TextView;
     var textDeliveryCityAndZip = view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.textDeliveryCityAndZip) as TextView;

     //Assign this item's values to the various subviews            
     imageItem.SetImageResource(item.Image);
```

> ERROR LINE> textDeliveryNo.SetText(item.DeliveryNo, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
>           textDeliveryName.SetText(item.LocationName, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
>           textDeliveryAddress.SetText(item.Address, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
>           textDeliveryCityAndZip.SetText(item.City + ", " + item.PostalCode, TextView.BufferType.Normal);

the debugger stops at the ERROR LINE with the error:
Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException:

I tryied to clean, rebuild the project... restart VS 2010 but nothing.
If I comment this line it will compile but it will show "12345" or whatever I put on the android:text property.

I would apreciate any help I can get.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The overload of SetText you are using wants a resource id, when you just want to set it to a string (that happens to be a number).

Use this instead:

`txtDeliveryNo.Text = item.DeliveryNo.ToString ();`